# Meaning of parameters in torch.nn.conv2d

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

In the fastai cutting edge deep learning for coders course lecture 7.

```
 self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,10,kernel_size = 5,stride=1,padding=2)
```

Does 10 there mean the number of filters or the number activations the filter will give?

Comment: 10  suggests number of filters

Answer (score 63):

[Here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv2d) is what you may find

> torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, groups=1, bias=True, padding_mode='zeros')

Parameters

- in_channels (int) – Number of channels in the input image
- out_channels (int) – Number of channels produced by the convolution
- kernel_size (int or tuple) – Size of the convolving kernel
- stride (int or tuple, optional) – Stride of the convolution. (Default: 1)
- padding (int or tuple, optional) – Zero-padding added to both sides of the input (Default: 0)
- padding_mode (string, optional) – zeros
- dilation (int or tuple, optional) – Spacing between kernel elements. (Default: 1)
- groups (int, optional) – Number of blocked connections from input to output channels. (Default: 1)
- bias (bool, optional) – If True, adds a learnable bias to the output. (Default: True)

And this [URL](https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic/blob/master/README.md) has helpful visualization of the process.

So the `in_channels` in the beginning is 3 for images with 3 channels (colored images).
For images black and white it should be 1.
Some satellite images should have 4.

The `out_channels` is **the number of filters** and you can set this arbitrary.

Let's create an example to "prove" that.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
c = nn.Conv2d(1,3, stride = 1, kernel_size=(4,5))
print(c.weight.shape)
print(c.weight)
```

Out

```
torch.Size([3, 1, 4, 5])
Parameter containing:
tensor([[[[ 0.1571,  0.0723,  0.0900,  0.1573,  0.0537],
          [-0.1213,  0.0579,  0.0009, -0.1750,  0.1616],
          [-0.0427,  0.1968,  0.1861, -0.1787, -0.2035],
          [-0.0796,  0.1741, -0.2231,  0.2020, -0.1762]]],


        [[[ 0.1811,  0.0660,  0.1653,  0.0605,  0.0417],
          [ 0.1885, -0.0440, -0.1638,  0.1429, -0.0606],
          [-0.1395, -0.1202,  0.0498,  0.0432, -0.1132],
          [-0.2073,  0.1480, -0.1296, -0.1661, -0.0633]]],


        [[[ 0.0435, -0.2017,  0.0676, -0.0711, -0.1972],
          [ 0.0968, -0.1157,  0.1012,  0.0863, -0.1844],
          [-0.2080, -0.1355, -0.1842, -0.0017, -0.2123],
          [-0.1495, -0.2196,  0.1811,  0.1672, -0.1817]]]], requires_grad=True)
```

If we would alter the number of out_channels,

```
c = nn.Conv2d(1,5, stride = 1, kernel_size=(4,5))
print(c.weight.shape) # torch.Size([5, 1, 4, 5])
```

We will get 5 filters each filter 4x5 as this is our kernel size.
If we would set 2 channels, (some images may have 2 channels only)

```
c = nn.Conv2d(2,5, stride = 1, kernel_size=(4,5))
print(c.weight.shape) # torch.Size([5, 2, 4, 5])
```

our filter will have 2 channels.

I think they have terms from [this book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html) and since they haven't called it filters, they haven't used that term.

So you are right; filters are what conv layer is learning and the number of filters is the number of out channels. They are set randomly at the start.

Number of activations is calculated based on `bs` and image dimension:

```
bs=16
x = torch.randn(bs, 3, 28, 28)
c = nn.Conv2d(3,10,kernel_size=5,stride=1,padding=2)
out = c(x)
print(out.nelement()) #125440 number of activations
```

Comment: thank you prosti for the answer. It is the only place where I found something even a little relevant to the topic. Moreover, you proved everything and you are really precise, so cheers. I have a quick question, why don't we define the filters ? One writes the size of the filter, and how many output filters one wants, but how are they define ? I saw during lectures that there exists different versions of filters (blurring, up lines, horizontal lines etc...) so how does pytorch chose which one to use ?

Comment: Ah, filters are the freedom. They are set at random and learned during the learning process @MarineGalantin.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the docs https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Conv2d you have 3 in_channels and 10 out_channels so these 10 out_channels are @thefifthjack005 filters also known as features.

Comment: You are pointing on Conv3d rather than on Conv2d form the quest.